# JS / JQuery keydown cycle through sub nav (focus function) doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, accessibility, keydown, onfocus

For accessibility i am required to have extended focus functionality on my navigation. on focus the sub nav displays, if the down or up keys are pressed the jquery will cycle through the items in the sub nav while maintaining focus. I have almost nailed this, however, the jquery next() isn't working as expected, instead it skips two or sometimes just goes in a random order.

HTML :-

```
<nav class="nav nav--primary" role="navigation">

            <a href="/" title="Home" class="primary-nav-link parent active" data-position="1" tabindex="1">wasd</a>

           <div class="nav__dropdown">
                    <a class="primary-nav-link parent " tabindex="1">wasd</a>
                <span class="nav__expand"></span>
                <div class="nav__dropdown__content" aria-hidden="true">
                        <a href="#" class="sub-nav-link" tabindex="-1" data-position="3.1">wasd</a>
                        <a href="#" class="sub-nav-link" tabindex="-1" data-position="3.2">wasd</a>
                        <a href="#" class="sub-nav-link" tabindex="-1" data-position="3.3">wasd</a>
                        <a href="#" class="sub-nav-link" tabindex="-1" data-position="3.4">wasd</a>
                        <a href="#" class="sub-nav-link" tabindex="-1" data-position="3.5">wasd</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="nav__dropdown">
                    <a class="primary-nav-link parent " tabindex="1">wasd</a>
                <span class="nav__expand"></span>
                <div class="nav__dropdown__content" aria-hidden="true">
                        <a href="#" class="sub-nav-link" tabindex="-1" data-position="3.1">wasd</a>
                        <a href="#" class="sub-nav-link" tabindex="-1" data-position="3.2">wasd</a>
                        <a href="#" class="sub-nav-link" tabindex="-1" data-position="3.3">wasd</a>
                        <a href="#" class="sub-nav-link" tabindex="-1" data-position="3.4">wasd</a>
                        <a href="#" class="sub-nav-link" tabindex="-1" data-position="3.5">wasd</a>
                </div>
            </div>

             <div class="nav__dropdown">
                    <a class="primary-nav-link parent " tabindex="1">wasd</a>
                <span class="nav__expand"></span>
                <div class="nav__dropdown__content" aria-hidden="true">
                        <a href="#" class="sub-nav-link" tabindex="-1" data-position="3.1">wasd</a>
                        <a href="#" class="sub-nav-link" tabindex="-1" data-position="3.2">wasd</a>
                        <a href="#" class="sub-nav-link" tabindex="-1" data-position="3.3">wasd</a>
                        <a href="#" class="sub-nav-link" tabindex="-1" data-position="3.4">wasd</a>
                        <a href="#" class="sub-nav-link" tabindex="-1" data-position="3.5">wasd</a>
                </div>
            </div>

</nav>
```

JS :-

```
   $(".parent").focus(function(){

    $(this).closest(".nav__dropdown").addClass("hover"); 
    $('.hover .nav__dropdown__content a').first().addClass('navSelected');

        $(document).keydown(function(e) {
            var selected = $('.navSelected');
            var sub = $('.hover .nav__dropdown__content a');


            if(e.which === 40){

                if(selected){
                    selected.removeClass('navSelected');
                    next = selected.next();
                        if(next.length > 0){
                            selected = next.addClass('navSelected');
                        }else{
                            selected = sub.eq(0).addClass('navSelected');
                        }
                }else{
                    selected = sub.eq(0).addClass('navSelected');
                }


            }else if(e.which === 38){
                if(selected){
                    selected.removeClass('navSelected');
                    next = selected.prev();
                    if(next.length > 0){
                selected = next.addClass('navSelected');
                    }else{
                        selected = sub.last().addClass('navSelected');
                    }
                }else{
                selected = sub.last().addClass('navSelected');
                }
            }
        });

}).blur(function(){     
    $(".nav__dropdown").removeClass("hover");
    $(document).removeClass("navSelected");
})
```

working js fiddle :-

https://jsfiddle.net/zpnfzevb/

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this problem in the jsfiddle.

Comment: Click at the top to the right of the first nav link then hit tab twice to get the focus on the right element and you'll see the subnav with green selected element, press the up and down keys and you'll notice it doesn't cycle in the correct order.

Comment: It is not a random order. Each menu has a pattern: A: 1,3,5,2,4; B: 5,4,3,2,1; C: 1,3,5,2,4. I would check your math. I would also dump each `tabindex` as you have duplicate values and you are breaking tabbing altogether (since the menu lacks `role=menu` a user cannot expect the arrows to work). In short, revisit what "For accessibility" means as I think you were given poor technical requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the response Adrian but you're wrong, tabindex="-1" means the the element can not be focused on using the tab key, which is what i need. The keydown event bound to the document was causing me issues,  essentially it was getting stuck in an loop, i now only bind the function to <nav> and i unbind the function on blur. all sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the keydown event bound to $(document) was causing extra loops meaning the selection would end up in different places.

The event is now bound to $('nav') and is unbound in the blur function, this has removed any unwanted triggers and now behaves as expected.

Final JS below:-

```
  $(".parent").focus(function(){

    $(this).closest(".nav__dropdown").addClass("hover"); 
    $('.hover .nav__dropdown__content a').first().addClass('navSelected');

        $('nav').keydown(function(e) {
            var selected = $('.navSelected');
            var sub = $('.hover .nav__dropdown__content a');


            if(e.which === 40){

                if(selected){
                    selected.removeClass('navSelected');
                    next = selected.next();
                        if(next.length > 0){
                            selected = next.addClass('navSelected');
                        }else{
                            selected = sub.eq(0).addClass('navSelected');
                        }
                }


            }
            if(e.which === 38){
                if(selected){
                    selected.removeClass('navSelected');
                    next = selected.prev();
                        if(next.length > 0){
                            selected = next.addClass('navSelected');
                        }else{
                            selected = sub.last().addClass('navSelected');
                        }
                }
            }

            if(e.which === 13){
                if(selected){
                selected.trigger('click');
                }
            }

        })

  }).blur(function(){
  $('nav').unbind('keydown');
  $(".nav__dropdown").removeClass("hover");
  $(document).removeClass("navSelected");
  })
```